# Using java generic types with wild card "?"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

While trying to understand java generic types and usage of wild card "?", I tried the following:

1. `List<?> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
2. `List<Integer> li2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
3. `li2.add(new Integer(6));`
4. `li = li2;`

The above compiles and runs fine. But if I try:

```
li.add(new Integer(5));
```

I get following compilation error (using Oracle JDeveloper as IDE):

```
Error(24,9):  cannot find method add(java.lang.Integer)
```

Why does the above not compile but the assignment `li=li2` is fine? Also if I want to call `li.add(...)` what is an acceptable parameter value?

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a wildcard type, encompassing all reference types. Values that are going to be assigned to the type `?` must be assignable to any reference type. `Integer` is not assignable to all reference types (for example, `String s = new Integer(1);` fails). In fact, in Java the only value assignable to all reference types is `null`, which is the only value you can add to `List<?>`

Other fun combinations:

`? super Number` is a range including types `Object` and `Number`. When you write such a value, it has to be both `Object` and `Number`, ie. `Integer` would be okay. When reading such a value, it will be either `Object` or `Number` (so, `Object`).

`? extends Number` is a range including types `Number` and all its subtypes. When you write such a value, it has to be of a type of all subtypes of Number, ie. it has to be `null`. When reading such a value, it will be a `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

A call to "li" will not bother whether you assigned it an `ArrayList<Integer>` or a `LikedList<String>`, it will work only on the declared type, that is `List<?>`.

When you declare a generic parameter, it can be applied to return types and to method arguments. For example, in a `List<String>`, you will have a `String get(int i)` and a `void add(String)` methods.

Both are safe, cause with this methods you can only add (and retrieve) String's from the list.

On a `List<?>` you will have a `Object get(int i)` method, because whatever is in the list it can safely be cast to Object, be it Integer or String.

However, offering a `void add(Object)` method, is unsafe, cause would permit you to add a String to an Integer list or vice versa (or any other thing).